# Add user access to a shared folder in remote computer

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-prompt, wmic

My objective is to add users to a shared folder in the remote server. I know that netshare command can be used to add users to local folder.

```
net share PathName=D:/Projects /GRANT:XXXX,FULL
```

When i run the above command in the local machine, it works fine.

Since the shared folder is present in remote server, i tried wmic and the psExec options. But both did not work. Not sure what i am missing here

```
wmic /node:ComputerName process call create "cmd.exe net share PathName=D:/Projects /GRANT:XXXX,FULL"
```

and

```
psExec \\ComputerName cmd.exe "net share PathName=D:/Projects /GRANT:XXXX,FULL"
```

Comment: Are you looking at altering SMB share access, or NTFS folder ACLs? I'm not sure which of those `net share` affects.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician `net share /grant` affects SMB authorization, not filesystem access

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, looking for smb share access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're running Windows 8 (Server 2012) or newer, use the [`Grant-SmbShareAccess` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635705(v=wps.630).aspx) and a [remote CIM session](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/08/24/introduction-to-cim-cmdlets/):

```
$RemoteSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName RemoteComputerName
Grant-SmbShareAccess -Name ShareName -AccountName XXXX -AccessRights Full -CimSession $RemoteSession
```

On Windows 7, you can use `Invoke-Command` to run the `net share` command on the remote machine:

```
$RemoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName RemoteComputerName
Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ScriptBlock { net share PathName=D:/Projects /GRANT:XXXX,FULL }
```

Comment: Error message received - New-CimSession : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the
destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service
running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following
command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig".

Comment: Do as the error tells you, configure WimRM on the target machine

Comment: Installed the winRM and now 1st line is executed successfully. But when i enter the second line, i am getting this error - Grant-SmbShareAccess : The term 'Grant-SmbShareAccess' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.

Comment: @Prem Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: My local machine (where i am running this command) is Windows 7 and remote servers are windows 2008 R2 Server

Comment: I tried running this command from a different machine (windows server 2008 R2) but getting the same error

Comment: @Prem See the note at the start of my answer about being on Windows 8 or Server 2012 or newer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107886/discussion-between-prem-and-mathias-r-jessen).